# Exporting whole page to excel instead of specific query

Tags: php, mysql

Okey, I have problem, I want to export data from MYSQL db to excel using PHP, but it export the whole page, not only the table from database.
There is my code:

```
<?php


                    if(isset($_GET['submit2']))
                    {
                        $vardas=$_GET['vardas']; //to rename the file
                        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$vardas.'.xls'); 
                        header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
                        header('Pragma: no-cache');
                        header('Content-Type: application/x-msexcel; charset=windows-1251; format=attachment;');
                        $msg="";
                        $var="";
                        //write your query      
                        $sql="SELECT laikas,Nuoroda "
        .               "FROM " . TBL_NUORODOS . " ORDER BY laikas DESC,Nuoroda";
                        $res = mysql_query($sql);
                        $numcolumn = mysql_num_fields($res); //will fetch number of field in table
                        $msg="<table><tr><td>Sl No</td>";
                        for ( $i = 0; $i < $numcolumn; $i++ ) {
                            $msg.="<td>";
                            $msg.= mysql_field_name($res, $i);  //will store column name of the table to msg variable
                            $msg.="</td>";

                        }
                        $msg.="</tr>";
                        $i=0;
                        $count=1; //used to print sl.no
                        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))  //fetch all the row as array
                        {

                            $msg.="<tr><td>".$count."</td>";
                            for($i=0;$i< $numcolumn;$i++)
                            {
                                $var=$row[$i]; //will store all the values of row 
                                $msg.="<td>".$var."</td>";
                            }
                            $count=$count+1;
                            $msg.="</tr>";
                        }

                        $msg.="</table>";
                        echo $msg;  //will print the content in the exel page
                    }
                    ?>
```

I only want to export this query : $sql="SELECT laikas,Nuoroda "
        .               "FROM " . TBL_NUORODOS . " ORDER BY laikas DESC,Nuoroda"; to my excel
Thanks

Comment: So are you including this file from another script that generates the rest of your page?

Comment: @MarkBaker I do not really understand what you mean, but I do not include any files in this function

Comment: So this script is being run directly from the request? You're not running any other script first? And this is the entirety of your script?

Comment: Do I need any other scripts to export ?  I found this script in this website and the changed to use my variables and now it exports whole page not only table from database @MarkBaker

Comment: No you don't need other scripts to export (unless you want to create a real Excel file instead of a pretend one)..... but you say that something is putting the rest of your page in this export; if so, then the rest of your page has to come from somewhere, so the request is doing something more than what is shown in the code that you've posted

Comment: @MarkBaker so in my file that has script can not be anything else just script?

Comment: There can't be anything else that generates output, unless you want that output in your "Excel file"

Comment: but how do I do if I want to make it on click on different page? I have script with function in other file and I including it in the file in which I want to press that button, but I still get whole page? @MarkBaker